# Get the source of a webpage after asynchronous data is loaded

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to retrieve the page source of a page on another domain after it has loaded the content it gathers asynchronously.

I have tried PHP's **file_get_contents**, but this does not obtain the source code after the asynchronous data is loaded.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can do that using PHP's `file_get_contents` or even using `cURL`. You have to look into other options.

Like, PHP's V8js module: http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

or you can try to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

What you are looking for is basically a way to execute the JavaScript from with in php.

Ofcourse you could always peep into the asynchronous requests on the page, and make your own requests too!